# ComboBox selection returning IndexOutofBounds Error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am setting up such that the choice of my first combobox(name = combo3) determines what the second combobox(name = combo4) will show. This works fine.

Now I am trying to make the second combobox determine what my third combobox will show. This doesn't work. The moment I make a selection on the second combox, it jams and returns error. But if I hard code the value of the 2nd combobox, it works.

I am getting indexoutofbounds exception. Problem seems to be with the method private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged2(). Please advice what is wrong. Thanks.

MainWindow

```
string[] tableArray = { "Agent_Name", "Agent_Age", "Agent_Gender", "Agent_Alias", "Security_Clearance", "Dept_ID", "Job_ID", "Mission_ID" };
string[] attributeArray = { "Mission_Name", "Mission_Description", "Mission_Country", "Mission_City" };

private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)  
        {
            if (((ComboBoxItem)combo3.SelectedItem).Content.ToString() == "Agents")
            {
                combo4.Items.Clear();
                foreach (string x in tableArray)
                {
                    combo4.Items.Add(x);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                combo4.Items.Clear();
                foreach (string x in attributeArray)
                {
                    combo4.Items.Add(x);
                }
            }
        }

private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged2(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            combo5.Items.Clear();
            MessageBox.Show(combo4.Text); //debugging line returns empty which shouldn't be the case. I chose Mission_Name thus it should show Mission_Name. 
            //fillCombo("SELECT * FROM " + combo3.Text + ";", "Mission_Name", combo5); //works   
            fillCombo("SELECT * FROM " + combo3.Text + ";", combo4.Text, combo5); // not working
        } 

private void fillCombo(string query, string name, ComboBox c)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmdReader = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            myReader = cmdReader.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string temp = myReader.GetString(name);
                c.Items.Add(temp);
            }
            myReader.Close();
        }
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="combo3" Width="120" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged1">
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="box3" Content="Agents"/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="box4" Content="Missions"/>
            </ComboBox>
            <ComboBox x:Name="combo4" Width="120" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged2">
            </ComboBox>
<ComboBox x:Name="combo5" Width="120" Canvas.Left="818" Canvas.Top="588"/>
```

Error Message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find specified column in results:

How the combo boxes looks.

[image]

Comment: What is the string being generated by SelectionChanged3 before querying the DB? did you make sure it is generating a valid column?

Comment: I ran a MessageBox.Show(combo4.Text); at SelectionChanged2. It returns an empty messageBox. I don't get it cos clearly I have selected a value in combo4 (I chose Mission_Name).

Comment: Guess that is the error but I don't get how it returns empty. All the codes related to this portion of execution are these. Do advice if you spot something. Thanks.

Comment: Insert a breakpoint at the line and see when `ComboBox_SelectionChanged2` event is fired. It seems it is fired when no item is added in Combo4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
MessageBox.Show(combo4.Text);
```

With this:

```
MessageBox.Show(combo4.SelectedText);
```

Or with this:

```
MessageBox.Show(combo4.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

replace everywhere you use combo4.Text as-well as combo1 2 3 and so on

Comment: Changing to the above line returns the value correctly as to what I chose so guess no error on this part.

Comment: Just make sure you check that `combo1.SelectedItem!=null` to avoid exceptions

Answer (score 0):

As i said in the comments, there is a problem with the string being generated to query that database.

Try debugging your application and set a breakpoint to your combobox4.Text property and see what it generates.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the `ComboBox_SelectionChanged2` event to run the code to fill out your comboboxes, but you aren't validating that the comboboxes have selections made before running the code.  This event will be triggered when the combobox is painted on the form *with no value selected in some of the other comboboxes*.  You just need to put a conditional in your event that ensures that your comboboxes have values before trying to access them.

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged2(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (combo3.Text.Length > 0 && combo4.Text.Length > 0)
        {
           combo5.Items.Clear();
           MessageBox.Show(combo4.Text); //debugging line returns empty which shouldn't be the case. I chose Mission_Name thus it should show Mission_Name. 
           //fillCombo("SELECT * FROM " + combo3.Text + ";", "Mission_Name", combo5); //works   
           fillCombo("SELECT * FROM " + combo3.Text + ";", combo4.Text, combo5); // not working
        }
    }
```